# How to create a new release in google console

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-play, release, production

In google console production tab, I have only "edit releases" button instead of a "create new release" button. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8hXs.png)

Answer (score 3):

[image: First Image is showing the drafted release]

You have already uploaded the apk file which has been saved in the library against this app in you google play console. If you want to create new release instead of the uploaded apk file, then you have to discard the previous one from the button in releases menu.

[image: After discarding the drafted release , new release option is enabled]

Answer (score 2):

You currently have a draft release. Either publish or delete your draft and you will be able to create a new release.